# property placeholder in class attribute of a bean

Tags: java, spring

A colleague of mine and I are playing around with the following spring configuration:

```
<beans>
   <context:property-placeholder location='classpath:/configuration.properties'/>
    <bean id="myBean" class="${type}" />
</beans>
```

We want to be able to provide a environment specific implementation of `myBean`. On a developers system the value of `type` would be a lightweight implementation of whatever `myBean` does. And in a production environment we would use a full-blown version.

When my colleague runs the code, everything works. When I run the code, I get a `ClassNotFoundException`, because spring tries to instantiate `${type}.class`. And it is not like it sometimes works and sometimes does not. On my machine it always fails and on my colleagues machine it always works.

Does anybody knows what the problem is?

Thx in advance,
Yevgeniy

**UPDATE**

as requested, here is how we load the application context:

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("application-configuration.xml");
```

the content of the properties file is pretty simple:

```
type=foobar.TestServiceImpl
```

Comment: Can you show how you load your `ApplicationContext`? I'd also like to see the contents of `configuration.properties`.

Comment: What else is different between your environments?

Comment: The only way I could see this happening is if you don't actually have the `<context:property-placeholder ...>` in your context configuration.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis different is the OS (me:Linux, he:Windows) everything else should be identical (versions of eclipse, jdk, tomcat)

Comment: any difference in version of Spring used?

Comment: the version of spring is the same too... the spring artifacts are downloaded by gradle from the same artifactory.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to override the class with a placeholder, I would like to suggest an alternative approach for your problem. You could use the [Profile](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.1.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-definition-profiles) functionality of Spring.

It would be simplier and safer to change the class depending of the environment.

```
<beans>
    <beans profile="dev">
        <bean id="myBean" class="dev.impl.MyBean" />
    </beans
    <beans profile="prod">
        <bean id="myBean" class="prod.impl.MyBean" />
    </beans
</beans>
```

You can then activate a given profile in development by adding the following system property to your server `-Dspring.profiles.active="dev"`.

You can define a default profile which will be used by adding the following to your `web.xml`:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>spring.profiles.default</param-name>
    <param-value>prod</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: we already have a alternative working approach. this is not what i was asking for. i would like to understand the different behaviour. thx anyway for your answer

Answer (score 1):

The following assumes Spring 3.1+.

I can tell you this much for sure. For Spring to fail with a `ClassNotFoundException` for class

```
${type}
```

means that it did not resolve the placeholder.

When you specify

```
<context:property-placeholder location='classpath:/configuration.properties'/>
```

Spring uses a `PropertyPlaceholderBeanDefinitionParser` to register either a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` or a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` bean which will do the placeholder resolution.

`PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` is a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`. This mean that it can modify bean definitions. Without going into much detail, if it cannot resolve a placeholder, the process fails with an `IllegalArgumentException` that states that the placeholder could not be resolved.

If you're saying that the `${type}` wasn't resolved, then no `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` or `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` beans were created. This probably means your context does not have

```
<context:property-placeholder location='classpath:/configuration.properties'/>
```

With the information you've shown us, that is what I think is going on. If you can prove otherwise, I'll ask you to provide a small reproducible example. Ideally, you would show the contents of your compiled project.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember property placeholder fails mutually. This means that if it cannot locate file `configuration.properties` on your machine the property is just not initialized.

To approve this assumption try to "break" the application on your colleague's machine: change the location to something wrong, e.g. `classpath:/configuration12345.properties`. I believe that the problem will appear on his machine too.

Now, check what's wrong in your environment and why this file cannot be found there.

BUT: do you have something against profiles? Spring provides a cool feature that is attended exactly for your use-case: [spring profiles](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RC1/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-3.1.html).

Comment: i have changed the location property of property-placeholder to something not existent (f.e. foobar.properties) and i get a different exception saying foobar.properties was not found, so i thing this is not the issue. thx anyway

Comment: The initialization of the context should fail with `Could not resolve placeholder`.

Comment: OK, so check your configuration.properties again. Is there a chance that you have 2 versions of this file and one of them does not contain property `type`?